# Upgrade from Ubuntu to Crunchbang?

Tags: ubuntu, crunchbang

Is there a way to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to Crunchbang without a full installation? I'd like to keep the files on the hard-drive intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.

At best, if you're reasonably neat, you'll be able to keep `/home` intact, but despite the fact that they're both Debian derivatives they're entirely different distributions.

Your "upgrade" is the rough equivalent of asking whether it's possible to turn a fedora core install into a SuSE one.